# Getting Ethernet computer to talk to wireless printer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, printer

Hopefully I'm posting in the right Stack community. And I'm not sure if this has already been asked because I have a hard time summarizing my problem and putting it in to words.

[Here's a diagram of my situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjkIV.png)

I have router that's basically acting like a switch. My computer has no Wi-Fi card, so I've connected it into the router via Ethernet. I have a Google Wi-Fi point that's connected to the router via Ethernet. I then have a wireless printer that's connected to the Wi-Fi point.

So, here's my main question: How can I connect to my printer from my computer?

Important things to note:

1. I can't connect the printer to the router because other devices on the WiFi need access to it.
2. I can't connect to the printer via USB because I already have one computer hooked up that way.
3. Again, my computer can't connect to Wi-Fi. It's Ethernet only.

Comment: You need to set the router up so it bridges the 2 networks (192.1681.x and 192.168.86.x). What are the model details for router and WiFi access point?

Comment: Another suggestion (similar results to the above post) would be to connect the wireless point via a LAN port on the wireless to a LAN port on the main router. Then turn DHCP OFF on the wireless so that everything is on one subnet including the printer. If your router is just a switch you may want to reverse the above

Comment: The router is a Netgear R6020, the WiFi point's model number is AC-1304. @John I will try changing from DHCP to Static on my Google WiFi router settings.

Answer (score 0):

To save you the hassle of a long winding trial and error of network configs, get an usb wifi dongle for the PC - make sure its supported by your OS Thats the quickest and cheapest way time wise to get it running.
Youcan plug it on a front or back usb port as it is really small Win from XP on and Linux support cost around 5-7$
As an example: Mini 150 Mbit/s MT7601 USB WiFi Wireless Adapter 802.11 B/G/N Networkcard LAN Dongle High Performance.
[image: WiFiDongle]

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://usermanual.wiki/Google/AC-1304), the Google AC-1304 does not allow you to change the WiFi settings on the access point. That implies you need to use some other method to connect your WiFi printer. The easiest would be to simply connect it to the router's WiFi network. If necessary, you can change the router's subnet to match that of the printer ([pg 84 of the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1265741/Netgear-R6120.html?page=84&term=ip%20address&selected=50)).